# ExtJs. How to make "Selected Item in the gridPanel" an orphan?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to somehow save "current selected record" in my GridPanel, then i want to delete GridPanel, create it again and set "current selected record" back.

**What is the best, or common way to do this?**

PS: or you can answer this, how to select record in GridPanel by record's "id" (for example)

Comment: why delete the entire gridPanel? Would it not be more effective to store the record in a variable, clear the store and then repopulate the gridStore with that single record? It would probably also require less code.

Comment: well.. it's just my app requre to do so... i want to delete grid in one place, then create it at another place... but when i do so, i losing my "current selected record"..

Comment: so busicly my app requre to "move" gridPanel from one place to another..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best method I can think of is storing the record in a variable by calling:

```
var record = gridPanel.getSelectionModel().getSelected();
```

Recreate your grid whenever it is needed then, assuming the new gridStore structure bound to the new grid is the same as the previous gridStore, you can call:

```
gridStore.add(record);
```

That should then add the record to your new store and thus to your new gridPanel. Hope it helps and I hope I understood your question correctly.

EDIT: You can also select the records by calling: `gridPanel.store.getById("id");`

EDIT2:

So to select a row in a gridPanel based on a record's ID you need to do 2 things.

1) Get the index of the record on the gridPanel:

```
var recordIndex = gridPanel.store.getIndexById("id");
```

2) Select the record on the gridPanel using the index:

```
gridPanel.getSelectionModel().selectRow(recordIndex);
```

Comment: you almost get me... let's look at this in other way.. i have two GridPanels, both of them binded to the diffrent stores (that load data from the same place) (so data1 === data2).. now i want select one row in first GridPanel, and want to select "same" row (row with same "id" for example) in other GridPanel...

Comment: Ah ok, yeah I understand now! give me a few minutes, I just need to finish something off, pretty sure I know how to do it.

Comment: I changed some code to make it work on ExtJs4, but it works as magic :) tnx a lot..

Comment: ah yeah, forgot to mention my code was ExtJs 3, haven't upgraded to 4 yet. Glad I could help :)

Comment: the only difference in ExtJS 4 is that you need to call:  
gridPanel.getSelectionModel().select(recordIndex);  
insted of:  gridPanel.getSelectionModel().selectRow(recordIndex);